# how to let crypt module only work when paramater values are identical to the given ones?

Tags: python, crypt

I've been trying to figure out how i can let this code only work when the values match the given ones through an cli on for example, ubuntu. The code works, but it still says the password matches the orginal one when i give another pass/hash than test/npDnXtpN5py4. anyone who can help? regards.

```
import os, sys
import getopt
import pwd
import crypt


def checkPassword(pswd, cpswd):
    """ Check if `cpwsd` an encrypted version is of `pswd`.
        Return `True` of `False`
    """
    try:
        cpswd = 'npDnXtpN5py4U'
        pswd = 'test'
        cryptedpassword = crypt.crypt(pswd, cpswd)
        return cpswd == cryptedpassword
    except KeyError:
        return 0 # no such pw

if __name__ == '__main__':
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'V', [])
    if len(args) != 2:
        print('Usage: {} [-v] <cpswd> <pswd>'.format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit(0)

    cpswd, pswd = args[0], args[1]
    res = checkPassword(pswd, cpswd)
    if res:
        print("Pass for '{}' is '{}'".format(
            cpswd, pswd))
    else:
        print("Pass for '{}' is not '{}'".format(
            cpswd, pswd))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code in `checkPassword(pswd, cpswd)`:

```
cpswd = 'npDnXtpN5py4U'
pswd = 'test'
```

...will overwrite the function's parameters, which are also called `pswd` and `cpswd`, so it'll essentially test whether `crypt.crypt('test', 'npDnXtpN5py4U') == 'npDnXtpN5py4U'`.

Apparently, `'npDnXtpN5py4U'` is a possible result of encrypting the string `'test'`, so the call `crypt.crypt('test', 'npDnXtpN5py4U')` will always return its last parameter:

```
>>> import crypt
>>> cpswd = 'npDnXtpN5py4U'
>>> pswd = 'test'
>>> crypt.crypt(pswd, cpswd)
'npDnXtpN5py4U'
```

All in all, the problem is that this function completely disregards the parameters passed to it and will always return the same result.

Comment: Okay, any knows what the code should be looking like to let it work like i want?

Comment: Well, `crypt.crypt` already can check if `cpswd` is an encrypted version of `pswd`: [Checking a password is usually done by passing the plain-text password as word and the full results of a previous `crypt()` call, which should be the same as the results of this call.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html#crypt.crypt) So your function could look like: `def checkPassword(pswd, cpswd): return crypt.crypt(pswd, cpswd) == cpswd`.